# How do I display the sub total and grand total in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt

so I need to display the Subtotal and Grand Total like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHc0M.jpg

But im getting this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa6JS.jpg

It seems its something to do with the for loop but im not entirely sure at this point.Its displaying the sub total under each and every title.

What am I doing wrong here?
Ive included my XSL and XML code below.

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="catalog">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Books Catalog by Author</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Books Catalog by Author</h1>
    <table border ="1" cellpadding ="5">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="book" group-by="author">
        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />

        <tr bgcolor="#ef9f37">
          <td colspan="4">Author:
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td><td>Title</td><td>Genre</td><td>Price</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="genre"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
        </tr>




        </xsl:for-each>


      </xsl:for-each-group>
      <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="right">Sub Total:</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<catalog>
 <book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk102">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk103">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
  <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
  society in England, the young survivors lay the 
  foundation for a new society.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk104">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
  <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
  agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
  for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
  Ascendant.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk105">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
  <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
  battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
  Oberon's Legacy.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk106">
  <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
  <title>Lover Birds</title>
  <genre>Romance</genre>
  <price>4.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
  <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
  conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk107">
  <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
  <title>Splish Splash</title>
  <genre>Romance</genre>
  <price>4.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
  <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
  thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk108">
  <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
  <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
  <genre>Horror</genre>
  <price>4.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
  <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
  centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk109">
  <author>Kress, Peter</author>
  <title>Paradox Lost</title>
  <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
  <price>6.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
  <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
  Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
  of being quantum.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk110">
  <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
  <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>36.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
  <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
  detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk111">
  <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
  <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>36.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
  <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
  detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
  SAX and more.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk212">
  <author>Galos, Mike</author>
  <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>49.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
  looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
  integrated into a comprehensive development 
  environment.</description>
</book>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Your code does not include any statements for the sub-totals. So, so far it CANNOT meet specifications yet. Please, include the source XML for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sum` function to simply sum the values of the nodes, along with `format-number` to display the result to 2 decimal places.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="catalog">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Books Catalog by Author</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Books Catalog by Author</h1>
    <table border ="1" cellpadding ="5">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="book" group-by="author">
        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
        <tr bgcolor="#ef9f37">
          <td colspan="4">Author:
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td><td>Title</td><td>Genre</td><td>Price</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="genre"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" align="right">Sub Total:</td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/price), '0.00')" /></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="right">Sub Total:</td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(book/price), '0.00')" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```